# Google Console Engine SSH sudo password

Tags: google-compute-engine

Recently, I just created an instance and use the web version of SSH. When I type the command

```
sudo -i
```

where it asks me for the user's password. I tried with my own password but there is no luck.

Anyone can help with that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at this post on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401834/how-to-get-password-for-sudo ?

Comment: Thanks for the help